# Why don't I need to extend TestCase when writing a test class using JUnit?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I am learning to write unit tests for my Android app (in Android Studio) and using xunitpatterns.com as a learning resource. My question is why don't I need to extend the TestCase class on my test classes? Just hoping this will help me better understand the framework and how the test runner works. What was the reason for needing to extend this class in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since v4 the JUnit test runner discovers tests by looking through a given path for classes which contain JUnit annotations such as `@Test`, `@Before`, `@After` etc.

So, a class is deemed a test case if it contains at least one public method having a JUnit annotation (though, of course, a class which has a `@Before` method but no `@Test` methods would be useless) and since JUnit discovers test cases by annotation there is no need to extend `TestCase`.

Prior to v3, JUnit used a class hierarchy approach so a class was deemed a test case if it implemented `TestCase`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, this means that JUnit will deem a class to be a test case if it: 1) Contains at least one public method having a JUnit annotation AND 2) Has the appropriate path?